# in unreal engine 4, what is the best way to increase microphone recording level?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

my UE4 'experience' allows the player to record an answer in voice, or create a new ask-all. the voice recorded from mic volume level is too low.

Answer (score 0):

the 'Set Volume Multiplier' node, with 'Audio Capture' component seems to work well. my voice recording blueprints based on Arthur's Audio BP's available on github.

[image]